# How to fix TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments but got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code raises `TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments but got 3`. I am unsure how to fix this.

```
def leg_count(w):
    x = input("How many legs does a", w, "have? ")
    print("A", w, "has", x, "legs")

leg_count("crocodile")
```

Comment: Thanks so much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `input` takes a single argument. It cannot be used the same way as `print` which will take and print multiple arguments. You will need to use `str.format` to do what you want.

```
def leg_count(w):
    x = input("How many legs does a {} have? ".format(w))
    print("A", w, "has", x, "legs")
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If that answer was helpful feel free to accept it. This will help other users find good answers and will provide you with good reputation that grants you priviledge through the site

Answer (score 0):

```
def leg_count(w):
    x = input("How many legs does a  " + w + "  have ?: ")
    print ("A " + w + " has " + str(x) + " legs")


leg_count("crocodile")
```

if you look input documentation :
input has an optional parameter, which is the prompt string. So you need to pass as a string.

Comment: You do not need to do the same for print as it can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Yes! I saw your answer and understood my mistake. Thank You!